How to add id to each element in this case?
Given this code:


var words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];

document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML = arr2tbl(2);

function arr2tbl(ncols) {
  return words.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (i % ncols == 0) a.push([]);
    a.at(-1).push(c);
    return a;
  }, []).map(r => "<tr>" + r.map(c => `<td>${c}</td>`).join("") + "</tr>").join("\n");
}
<table id="wordTable"></table>



the code prints out this table
<table>
<tr>
<td>ac</td> <td>bd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>bf</td> <td>uy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ca</td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>

But I want to assign id for each word so that I can format them dynamicaly
something like this
<table>
<tr>
<td id="1">ac</td>  <td id="2">bd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="3">bf</td>  <td id="4">uy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="5">ca</td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>

So that later on I can have a fuction like this
function formatWord (wordID){
  document.getElementById(wordID).style.color ="red";
}

Users can call formatWord (2); formatWord (5);.. randomly
If we can not do this with "td", it doesn't matter. As long as I can format the words in the table dynamically.
How to add id to each element in this case?

Another (imho more simple) way to create the table, without innerHTML


arr2tbl( 
  ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'], 
  document.querySelector(`#wordTable`), 
  2 );

document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = 
  document.querySelector(`#wordTable`).outerHTML;

function arr2tbl(words, forTable, ncols) {
  let currentRow = document.createElement(`tr`);
  forTable.append(currentRow);
  
  words.forEach( (word, i) => {
     if (i > 0 && i % ncols === 0) {
        forTable.append(currentRow.cloneNode());
     }
     
     forTable.querySelector(`tr:last-child`).append(
      Object.assign( document.createElement(`td`), 
      { id: i + 1, textContent: word } ) );
  });
}
<table id="wordTable"></table>
<h3>The table html</h3>
<pre></pre>




We can pass the index value into the array when reducing


var words=['ac', 'bd', 'bf','uy','ca'];

let result = arr2tbl(2)
console.log(result)
document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML=result;

function arr2tbl(ncols){
 return words.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
 if(i%ncols==0)a.push([]);
   a.at(-1).push([c,i+1]);
   return a;
  },[]).map(r=>"<tr>"+r.map(c=>`<td id="${c[1]}">${c[0]}</td>`).join("")+"</tr>").join("\n");
}
<table id="wordTable"></table>




I think this is easier to read.
I would not myself choose numeric IDs but rather something like
const idx = `row-${rowStartIndex}-cell${cellIndex}`;



const words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];

const arr2tbl = (ncols) => {
  // Calculate the number of rows needed
  const nrows = Math.ceil(words.length / ncols);

  // Create an array of rows using the function argument of Array.from
  return Array.from({ length: nrows }, (_, rowIndex) => {
    // Calculate start index of the current row in the original array to stay DRY
    const rowStartIndex = rowIndex * ncols;

    // For each row, create an array of cell strings
    const cells = words.slice(rowStartIndex, rowStartIndex + ncols)
      .map((word, cellIndex) => {
        // Calculate the index of the word in the original array for ID
        const idx = (rowStartIndex + cellIndex)+1; // one based
        // const idx = `row-${rowStartIndex}-cell${cellIndex}`;
        return `<td id="${idx}">${word}</td>`;
      })
      .join(''); // Join the cell strings to form a row

    return `<tr>${cells}</tr>`; // Wrap the row cells in <tr> tags
  }).join('\n');
};
document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML = arr2tbl(2);
<table>
  <tbody id="wordTable"></tbody>
</table>




The simplest change from where you are is probably to map the cells before creating the rows:


var words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];

document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML = arr2tbl(2);

function arr2tbl(ncols) {
  return words
    .map((word, index) => `<td id="${index + 1}">${word}</td>`)
    .reduce((a, c, i) => {
      if (i % ncols == 0) a.push([]);
      a.at(-1).push(c);
      return a;
    }, [])
    .map((row) => "<tr>" + row.join("") + "</tr>").join("\n");
}
<table id="wordTable"></table>




You could pass along the index of the word like so:


let words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

document.getElementById('wordTable').innerHTML = arr2tbl(2);

function arr2tbl(ncols){
 return words.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
 if(i%ncols==0)a.push([]);
   a.at(-1).push([c, (i + 1)]);
   return a;
  },[]).map(r=>"<tr>"+r.map(c=>`<td id="${c[1]}">${c[0]}</td>`).join("")+"</tr>").join("\n");
}
<table id="wordTable" border="1"></table>




The id needs to starts with 1 ,not 0

@flyingfox you are correct, adjusted my code

You can do it as simple as possible with adding a variable called index and then ++ it on your preferred iteration.


var words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];

        document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML = arr2tbl(2);

        function arr2tbl(ncols) {
            var index = 1;
            return words.reduce((a, c, i) => {
                if (i % ncols == 0) a.push([]);
                a.at(-1).push(c);
                return a;
            }, []).map(r => "<tr>" + r.map(c => `<td id=${index++}>${c}</td>`).join("") + "</tr>").join("\n");
        }
<table id="wordTable"></table>



Good Luck!
